# Include glossary acronyms in other acronyms

Tags: acronyms, glossary

I would like to include one acronym in another using the glossary package, e.g. something like

```
\usepackage[acronym]{glossary}
\newacronym{a}{A}{apples}
\newacronym{ao}{AO}{apples oranges}

\begin{document}

A basket of \gls{ao} includes \gls{a}.

\end{document}
```

which currently results in

> A basket of apples oranges (AO) includes apples (A).

but I want to have

> A basket of apples oranges (AO) includes A.

How can I do this?

Comment: Do you really mean the [`glossary`](https://ctan.org/pkg/glossary) package rather than [`glossaries`](https://ctan.org/pkg/glossaries)?

Comment: uhm no, I am using glossaries but solely for acronyms in the text.

Comment: [`acro`](https://ctan.org/pkg/acro) has a simple built-in mechanism through the `uselist` key that can handle this exact case, and depending what edge cases there are acronyms can be adapted fairly easily with `\acroifused<TF>`.

Answer (score 0):

If what you're trying to do is get rid of the parentheses around "A," you can try the `\acrshort{}` command:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}

\newacronym{a}{A}{apples}
\newacronym{ao}{AO}{apples oranges}

\begin{document}

A basket of \gls{ao} includes \acrshort{a}.

\end{document}
```

Which produces

> [image]

If you want glossary.sty and not glossaries.sty, you can similarly try `\acrsh{}`.

Comment: thanks! in that case, however, I need to manually keep track of when which of the two is used first. I want something that does that automatically.

Comment: Based on your example it seems like apples (A) will always come before apples and oranges (AO) in the document. If that is the case, then by default the glossaries package will print the second instance of apples (A) without the parentheses. Are you looking for a solution that will always print the second acronym without parenthesis even if that term hasn't been used yet?

Answer (score 0):

`\glsunset` will mark an entry as used in [`glossaries`](https://ctan.org/pkg/glossaries). I believe the equivalent macro is `\unsetacronym` if you genuinely are using [`glossary`](https://ctan.org/pkg/glossaries)—consider switching if so.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}
\newacronym{a}{A}{apples}
\newacronym{ao}{AO}{apples oranges}

\begin{document}
A basket of \gls{ao}\glsunset{a} includes \gls{a}.
\end{document}
```

> A basket of apples oranges (AO) includes A.

Unfortunately trying to use this as `\newacronym{ao}{AO}{apples oranges\glsunset{a}}` gives an error, conventionally nesting the acronym as `\newacronym{ao}{AO}{\gls{a} oranges}` doesn't work either. There may be a way around this, but I'm missing it.

However you can patch  [`glossaries`](https://ctan.org/pkg/glossaries) manually to check against a stored set of dependent keys each time an acronym is marked as used and mark those dependents as used.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}
\newacronym{a}{A}{apples}
\newacronym{ao}{AO}{apples oranges}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_new:N \l_DurdnT_sub_seq
\seq_new:N \l_DurdnT_sup_seq
\NewDocumentCommand{\AddAcronymDep}{mm}{
\seq_put_right:Nn \l_DurdnT_sub_seq {#1}
\seq_put_right:Nn \l_DurdnT_sup_seq {#2}
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\CheckDependentAcronyms}{m}{
  \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl {#1}
  \seq_map_pairwise_function:NNN 
    \l_DurdnT_sup_seq
    \l_DurdnT_sub_seq
    \unsetgls_if:nn
}
\cs_new:Nn \unsetgls_if:nn {
  \tl_if_eq:NnT \l_tmpa_tl {#1} {
    \glsunset{#2}
  }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \renewcommand*{\glsunset}[1]{%
    \gls@ifnotmeasuring
    {%
      \glsdoifexists{#1}%
      {%
        \@glsunset{#1}%
        \CheckDependentAcronyms{#1}%
      }%
    }%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\AddAcronymDep{a}{ao}% Indicate that a should be marked used when ao is used

\begin{document}
\showoutput
A basket of \gls{ao} includes \gls{a}.
\end{document}
```

> A basket of apples oranges (AO) includes A.